# Android's CountDownTimer - increase or decrease the count

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android's [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class to make a coutndown timer. I have to admit that it's rather difficult for me understand it correctly, other solution would be to use timer instead, but does anyone know how can I decrease or increase the countdowntimer's by 10 seconds for an example?

Comment: I think for a countdown timer, you can't modify the count once it starts, though you can cancel the timer and construct a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel the current running timer and start another one.